# How to develop ABAP code without using ADT for ECLIPSE

Tags: eclipse, abap, sap-business-technology-platform, abap-adt

How to write ABAP code without eclipse editor?

I am new to ABAP development. I am learning ABAP for BTP development. I want to know how to write ABAP code without using the editor which has abstracted the writing process.

Comment: BTP requires Eclipse/ADT for ABAP development, so why this question?

Answer (score 3):

The classic way to develop ABAP code is by connecting to the system with the SAP Logon software and then going to the transaction code SE80 (ABAP Workbench).

But note that the SE80 is considered obsolete. Lots of newer features, like CDS views, ABAP managed database procedures or RESTful programming model, can only be developed using Eclipse. Some developers still cling to the SE80 out of habit (including me, occasionally), but for the long run you should really learn to do ABAP development in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, 
How to create local class for a global in abap workbrench? In eclipse you can follow the interface. But how is the structure.

Comment: @MirzonabotMirzonabotov If you have a followup question that goes beyond the scope of your original question, please post it as a  new question.